# Testing with Apache Camel AdviceWith and weaveById

Tags: java, dependency-injection, apache-camel

I am currently trying to test an existing route with Apache Camel, but I am not sure I am doing it correctly, because I don't fully understand all the concepts behind Camel.

That being said, here is what I would like to do, on the following example route :

```
public class TestExampleRoute extends SpringRouteBuilder {

    /** The Constant ENDPOINT_EDOSSIER_IMPORT. direct:edossierImport */
    public static final String ENDPOINT_EXAMPLE = "direct:testExampleEndpoint";

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        from(ENDPOINT_EXAMPLE).routeId("testExample")

            .bean(TestExampleProcessor.class, "getImportDocumentProcess").id("getImportDocumentProcess")
            .bean(TestExampleProcessor.class, "createImportDocumentTraitement").id("createImportDocumentTraitement")

            .to(BaseEndpoint.LOG_MESSAGE_SHOW_ALL_MULTILINE);
        // @formatter:on
    }

}
```

The point here is just to fetch an *ImportDocumentProcess* and create an *ImportDocumentTraitement* that depends on the previous object. The ImportDocumentProcess is passes through the exchange.

Here is the processor code :

```
@Component("testExampleProcessor")
public class TestExampleProcessor {

    /** The Constant LOGGER. */
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(TestExampleProcessor.class);

    @Autowired
    ImportDocumentTraitementService importDocumentTraitementService;

    @Autowired
    ImportDocumentProcessDAO importDocumentProcessDAO;

    @Autowired
    ImportDocumentTraitementDAO importDocumentTraitementDAO;

    // ---- Constants to name camel headers and bodies
    private static final String HEADER_ENTREPRISE = "entreprise";
    private static final String HEADER_UTILISATEUR = "utilisateur";
    private static final String HEADER_IMPORTDOCPROCESS = "importDocumentProcess";

    public void getImportDocumentProcess(@Header(HEADER_ENTREPRISE) Entreprise entreprise, Exchange exchange) {
        LOGGER.info("Entering TestExampleProcessor method : getImportDocumentProcess");

        Utilisateur utilisateur = SessionUtils.getUtilisateur();
        ImportDocumentProcess importDocumentProcess = importDocumentProcessDAO.getImportDocumentProcessByEntreprise(
                entreprise);

        exchange.getIn().setHeader(HEADER_UTILISATEUR, utilisateur);
        exchange.getIn().setHeader(HEADER_IMPORTDOCPROCESS, importDocumentProcess);
    }

    public void createImportDocumentTraitement(@Header(HEADER_ENTREPRISE) Entreprise entreprise,
            @Header(HEADER_UTILISATEUR) Utilisateur utilisateur,
            @Header(HEADER_IMPORTDOCPROCESS) ImportDocumentProcess importDocumentProcess, Exchange exchange) {
        LOGGER.info("Entering TestExampleProcessor method : createImportDocumentTraitement");

        long nbImportTraitementBefore = this.importDocumentTraitementDAO.countNumberOfImportDocumentTraitement();
        ImportDocumentTraitement importDocumentTraitement = this.importDocumentTraitementService.createImportDocumentTraitement(
                entreprise, utilisateur, importDocumentProcess, "md5_fichier_example_test", "fichier_example_test.xml");
        long nbImportTraitementAfter = this.importDocumentTraitementDAO.countNumberOfImportDocumentTraitement();

        exchange.getIn().setHeader("nbImportTraitementBefore", Long.valueOf(nbImportTraitementBefore));
        exchange.getIn().setHeader("nbImportTraitementAfter", Long.valueOf(nbImportTraitementAfter));
        exchange.getIn().setHeader("importDocumentTraitement", importDocumentTraitement);
    }

}
```

I have read a few things about *AdviceWith* and *WeaveById* and I would like to put test the state of the exchange between two pieces of route.

Here is my attempt for a processor test :

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:/camel-context.xml" })
public class TestExampleProcessorTest extends CamelTestSupport {

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() {
        return new TestExampleRoute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUseAdviceWith() {
        return true;
    }

    @Before
    public void mockEndPoints() throws Exception {
        context.getRouteDefinitions().get(0).adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                weaveById("getImportDocumentProcess").replace().multicast().to("mock:catchTestEndpoint");
            }
        });
    }

    @Test
    public void testAdvised() throws Exception {
        MockEndpoint mockEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:catchTestEndpoint");

        context.start();
        mockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
        mockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
        context.stop();
    }
```

}

One last thing : I am using **Camel 2.18.0.**

How can I test the state of the exchange between each piece of route ?
What am I missing ?

**EDIT :** Just edited the code of the the test class (Which compiles and works) BUT I get the following assertion error :

```
java.lang.AssertionError: mock://catchTestEndpoint Received message count. Expected: <1> but was: <0>
```

This adds one more question : why is the message not caught correctly ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you send any message to you testroute? I can't see that in the code. For example

template.sendBody("direct:testExampleEndpoint", "Hello World");

Comment: That was it ! Stupid error but as I said, I am not a camel expert. Thanks a lot for your help !